# Get part of string that matches regex

Tags: linux, bash, regex

I'm writing a bash script and trying to parse a file to get a software version. 
The output is :

```
Version 13.0.R7.0 - Built on Tue Feb 09 18:47:29 EST 2016
```

I want to be able to pull out `13.0` (I will later cut off the `.0`) with the regex `^1[0-9]\.0`, and pull out the `R7` with `R[0-9]{1}`.

I know how to match them, I just don't know how to put the value that matches the regex into a variable, is such a thing possible?

Comment: Does that mean that you could use `sed` or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU bash:

```
echo 'Version 13.0.R7.0 - Built on Tue Feb 09 18:47:29 EST 2016' | while IFS=" ." read -r a b c d rest; do echo $b $c $d; done
```

or

```
while IFS=" ." read -r a b c d rest; do echo $b $c $d; done < filename
```

Output:

```
13 0 R7
```

Comment: That works, but doesn't answer the question directly. Is there no way to pull a regex match into a variable? I've needed to do it multiple times

Comment: With an array: `IFS= read -r line < filename; [[ $line =~ Version\ ([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\. ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}`